# Can fortify static code analyzer scan visual studio 2013 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, fortify

I have web api 2 written in C# visual studio 2013 ,but i can not find a fortify sca plugin for it. Have anyone encountered same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no plugin yet for VS2013 in the latest SCA 4.02 version

Comment: This is too late. But now 4.21 supports Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Version 4.10 of Fortify that was released approximately April 16, 2014 does contain a plugin for Visual Studio 2013.